# Is there any way to immediately return response and do something async after in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How to send immediately a HTTP-response and do further processing afterwards in Spring Boot?

My code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class Application Configuration {
....
}
```

then a function in my Service which is long running and should be executed asynchronously

```
@Service
public class MyService {

@Async
public void executeDBUpdate() {
...log.info(Thread.getCurrentThread.getName());
}
}
```

and my Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/update")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public ResponseEntity<String> updateDB() {
...
   log.info(Thread.getCurrentThread.getName());
   ComparableFuture.runAsync(() - > myservice.executeDBUpdate());
   return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
```

I would expect that HttpStatus.ACCEPTED is send immediately and executeDBUpdate is running in separate Thread still further. Looking at thread name in fact I see different threads, so a new thread is used for executeDBUpdate.

But the HttpStatus.ACCEPTED is not send immediately, but only after the AsyncTask is done, even if in Debugger I see that updateDB() is processed immediately further

Is thee any way to send response immediately?

Comment: You don't need `runAsync` as the method is already `@Async` so you can just call the method on the service. You are now using 2 threads where you would use 1 otherwise (or actually 3 instead of 2).

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it. It works as designed, however not if you set Breakpoint in the application. If you debug and have breakpoints, processing is stopped here and response sending after leaving debugger.

Using Thread.sleep I see desired response